# Froala customisation with OctoberCMS - default values

Tags: javascript, octobercms, froala

I’m trying to customize the richeditor / froala editor. I have the following javascript code snippet which I inject with my custom plugin:

```
+function ($) { "use strict";
    $(document).render(function() {
        if ($.FroalaEditor) {
            $.FroalaEditor.DEFAULTS = $.extend($.FroalaEditor.DEFAULTS, {
                lineBreakerTags: ['figure','table','hr','iframe','form','dl', 'div.section', 'div.col-sm-6']
            });
        }
    })
}(window.jQuery);
```

Which works only if i remove line 628 (`froalaOptions.lineBreakerTags=['figure','table','hr','iframe','form','dl']`) from the file `modules/backend/formwidgets/richeditor/assets/js/build.min.js`. However this is obviously not preferred as I don’t want to touch any core files. Does anyone know how I can still change the lineBreakerTags used by the Froala editor without touching any core OctoberCMS files?